# Multiple for loop

Tags: shell, variables, for-loop, scripting

I'm trying to write a script that modifies a file. 
I want to check for defined text in the file, if it exists change it, if it doesn't add it. 
The text to change is defined in variables:

```
line1=text string 1
line2=text string 2
line3=text string 3
# new values
line1Arg=value 1
line2Arg=value 2
line3Arg=value 3
```

So far I have the following:

```
for i in $line1 $line2 $line3;
do
oldarg=`grep $i $file |cut -d"=" -f2`;
chkexists=`grep -c $i $file`
if [ $chkexists -eq 0 ]; then
cp $file $tmpfile
```

This is where I am stuck...
His do a loop over variables $linexArg and add that to $tmpfile?

```
echo $i='new value' >> $tmpfile;
echo "$i added with newvalue";
else
echo "$i exists with $oldarg";
```

Probably pretty simple but I'm new to scripting!

EDIT 1:

Thanks to Matt I now have this, which adds only 1 line from $line1-5, it should add 2 missing lines, $line4 and $line5

```
file=/folder/file
tmpfile=$file.tmp

#  strings to find and modify / add
line1=text string 1
line2=text string 2
line3=text string 3
line4=text string 4
line5=text string 5
# new values
line1Arg=120
line2Arg=370
line3Arg=100
line4Arg=999
line5Arg=1000

for i in $line1 $line2 $line3 $line4 $line5; 
do
result=`grep $i $file`
if [ -z $result ]
then
cp $file $tmpfile
echo $i >> $tmpfile
else
cat $file | sed "s/$i/$newi/g" > $tmpfile
fi
done
```

What I'm struggling with is how to loop over the 2 sets of variables and add the missing strings in format
    $line1=$line1Arg

EDIT 2

So now i have the following...

```
file=/folder/file
tmpfile=$file.tmp

#  strings to find and modify / add
line1=text string 1
line2=text string 2
line3=text string 3
line4=text string 4
line5=text string 5
# new values
line1Arg=120
line2Arg=370
line3Arg=100
line4Arg=999
line5Arg=1000

for i in $line1 $line2 $line3 $line4 $line5;
do
for x in $line1Arg $line2Arg $lineArg $line4Arg $line5Arg;
do

result=`grep $i $file`
oldarg=`grep $i $file |cut -d"=" -f2`

if [ -z $result ]
then
cp $file $tmpfile
echo $i=$x >> $tmpfile
echo "$i added with value $x"

else

if [ "$oldarg" = "$x" ]; then
echo "$i already set - no change"

else
sed "s/$i=.*/$i=${x}/g" $file > $tmpfile
echo "$i changed to value $x"
fi
fi
done
```

But its not adding all missing $lineX=$lineXArg to the file?
what am i missing?

EDIT 3

OK so using sh -x i get the following output

```
> root@d802:/ # sh -x /data/local/build.sh
> + file=/sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + tmpfile=/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + line1=wifi.supplicant_scan_interval
> + line2=ro.sf.lcd_density
> + line3=ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality
> + line4=rixh.wallace
> + line5=ro.telephony.call_ring.delay
> + line1Arg=120
> + line2Arg=370
> + line3Arg=99999999
> + line4Arg=999
> + line5Arg=1000
> + grep wifi.supplicant_scan_interval /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120'
> + grep wifi.supplicant_scan_interval /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=120
> + '[' -z 'wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120' ']'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120/wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120/g'
> + grep wifi.supplicant_scan_interval /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120'
> + grep wifi.supplicant_scan_interval /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=120
> + '[' -z 'wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120' ']'
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + sed 's/wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120/wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=370/g'
> + grep wifi.supplicant_scan_interval /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120'
> + grep wifi.supplicant_scan_interval /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=120
> + '[' -z 'wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120' ']'
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120/wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=999/g'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + grep wifi.supplicant_scan_interval /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120'
> + grep wifi.supplicant_scan_interval /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=120
> + '[' -z 'wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120' ']'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120/wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=1000/g'
> + grep ro.sf.lcd_density /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='ro.sf.lcd_density=370'
> + grep ro.sf.lcd_density /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=370
> + '[' -z 'ro.sf.lcd_density=370' ']'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/ro.sf.lcd_density=370/ro.sf.lcd_density=120/g'
> + grep ro.sf.lcd_density /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='ro.sf.lcd_density=370'
> + grep ro.sf.lcd_density /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=370
> + '[' -z 'ro.sf.lcd_density=370' ']'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/ro.sf.lcd_density=370/ro.sf.lcd_density=370/g'
> + grep ro.sf.lcd_density /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='ro.sf.lcd_density=370'
> + grep ro.sf.lcd_density /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=370
> + '[' -z 'ro.sf.lcd_density=370' ']'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/ro.sf.lcd_density=370/ro.sf.lcd_density=999/g'
> + grep ro.sf.lcd_density /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='ro.sf.lcd_density=370'
> + grep ro.sf.lcd_density /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=370
> + '[' -z 'ro.sf.lcd_density=370' ']'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/ro.sf.lcd_density=370/ro.sf.lcd_density=1000/g'
> + grep ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100'
> + grep ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=100
> + '[' -z 'ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100' ']'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100/ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=120/g'
> + grep ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100'
> + grep ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=100
> + '[' -z 'ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100' ']'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100/ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=370/g'
> + grep ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100'
> + grep ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=100
> + '[' -z 'ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100' ']'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100/ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=999/g'
> + grep ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result='ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100'
> + grep ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=100
> + '[' -z 'ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100' ']'
> + cat /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + >/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + sed 's/ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=100/ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality=1000/g'
> + grep rixh.wallace /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result=
> + grep rixh.wallace /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=
> + '[' -z ']'
> + cp /sdcard/documents/build.txt /sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + >>/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + echo 'rixh.wallace=120'
> + grep rixh.wallace /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result=
> + grep rixh.wallace /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=
> + '[' -z ']'
> + cp /sdcard/documents/build.txt /sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + >>/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + echo 'rixh.wallace=370'
> + grep rixh.wallace /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result=
> + grep rixh.wallace /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=
> + '[' -z ']'
> + cp /sdcard/documents/build.txt /sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + >>/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + echo 'rixh.wallace=999'
> + grep rixh.wallace /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result=
> + grep rixh.wallace /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=
> + '[' -z ']'
> + cp /sdcard/documents/build.txt /sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + >>/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + echo 'rixh.wallace=1000'
> + grep ro.telephony.call_ring.delay /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result=
> + grep ro.telephony.call_ring.delay /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=
> + '[' -z ']'
> + cp /sdcard/documents/build.txt /sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + >>/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + echo 'ro.telephony.call_ring.delay=120'
> + grep ro.telephony.call_ring.delay /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result=
> + grep ro.telephony.call_ring.delay /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=
> + '[' -z ']'
> + cp /sdcard/documents/build.txt /sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + >>/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + echo 'ro.telephony.call_ring.delay=370'
> + grep ro.telephony.call_ring.delay /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result=
> + grep ro.telephony.call_ring.delay /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=
> + '[' -z ']'
> + cp /sdcard/documents/build.txt /sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + >>/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + echo 'ro.telephony.call_ring.delay=999'
> + grep ro.telephony.call_ring.delay /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + result=
> + grep ro.telephony.call_ring.delay /sdcard/documents/build.txt
> + cut '-d=' -f2
> + oldarg=
> + '[' -z ']'
> + cp /sdcard/documents/build.txt /sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + >>/sdcard/documents/build.txt.tmp
> + echo 'ro.telephony.call_ring.delay=1000'
```

EDIT 4

Current code:

```
#/system/bin/sh

file=/sdcard/documents/build.txt
tmpfile=$file.tmp


# props to change

line1=wifi.supplicant_scan_interval

line2=ro.sf.lcd_density

line3=ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality

line4=rixh.wallace

line5=ro.telephony.call_ring.delay


# new values

line1Arg=120

line2Arg=480

line3Arg=99999999

line4Arg=999

 line5Arg=6666666666666



for i in $line1 $line2 $line3 $line4 $line5; do

for x in $line1Arg $line2Arg $lineArg $line4Arg $line5Arg; do

result=`grep $i $file`
oldarg=`grep $i $file |cut -d"=" -f2`

if [ -z $result ]
then
cp $file $tmpfile
echo $i=$x >> $tmpfile;
echo "$i added with value $x"
else
cat $file | sed "s/$i=$oldarg/$i=$x/g"> $tmpfile
echo "$i edited to $x"

fi

done
done
```

and the output:

```
ro.telephony.call_ring.delay added with value 6666666666666
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval edited to 120
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval edited to 480
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval edited to 999
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval edited to 6666666666666
ro.sf.lcd_density edited to 120
ro.sf.lcd_density edited to 480
ro.sf.lcd_density edited to 999
ro.sf.lcd_density edited to 6666666666666
ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality edited to 120
ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality edited to 480
ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality edited to 999
ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality edited to 6666666666666
rixh.wallace added with value 120
rixh.wallace added with value 480
rixh.wallace added with value 999
rixh.wallace added with value 6666666666666
ro.telephony.call_ring.delay added with value 120
ro.telephony.call_ring.delay added with value 480
ro.telephony.call_ring.delay added with value 999
 ro.telephony.call_ring.delay added with value 6666666666666
```

Comment: what's wrong with `sed -i 's/text string/value/' file` ?

Comment: @glennjackman Id prefer to write to a temp file, so i can check the changes are made and then copy the temp file to $file

Comment: `sed 's/text string/value/' file > file.new`

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but could you elaborate in that and explain?

Comment: if it's not too much work, can you give some sample input/output? particularly in the problem sections?

Comment: @Matt Added sh -x output

Comment: @Matt Any ideas here?

Comment: To clarify, is the problem so patterns are not getting matched? or is it that when they are getting matched, it is changing them incorrectly?

Comment: @Matt It seems to be matching ok. Its just not writing the missing patterns to $file

Comment: sorry to be thick, can you give me an example of something that it needs to write to the file and is not?

Comment: @Matt Just looking a bit closer. And it looks as though its adding one new pattern only and not amending already existing patterns. From my above example its adding $line5=$line5Arg but not the other. Nor is it amending pattern's that exist that i want to amend. In this example $line2. It should change the end too the new specified value %line2Arg

Comment: @Matt Oh and you're not being thick. Its probably me being thick and not explaining clearly enough what I want!

Comment: I'm trying to grasp at possibilities especially if it succeeds for one or some, but not all. Do you have a second "done" command to close your outer for loop? (and are you sure it's setting the one matched to the correct value? It may be, but it would be good to confirm in our hunt for potential problems)

Comment: @Matt I have 2 done commands one after another. It seems to be changing things 3 times? But not making changes to the file? This is confusing me more now!

Comment: @Matt Script added with output

Comment: So it nests the two loops and matches each pattern for every lineX value... you need to iterate through two lists concurrently. I will think of a solution for this. I think it involves the shift and cut commands. Will lineX and lineXargs always go up to the same number?

Comment: @Matt Yes $lineX and line $lineXArg will always go up the same number. So if there are 5 $line, there will be 5 $LineArg, 6 $line, then 6 $lineArg.

Comment: I editted my answer with some new code. Pulled something I hadn't see before, we'll see how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this

```
#/system/bin/sh

file=/sdcard/documents/build.txt
tmpfile=$file.tmp


# props to change

line1=wifi.supplicant_scan_interval
line2=ro.sf.lcd_density
line3=ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality
line4=rixh.wallace
line5=ro.telephony.call_ring.delay


# new values

line1Arg=120
line2Arg=480
line3Arg=99999999
line4Arg=999
line5Arg=6666666666666

linex=$line1,$line2,$line3,$line4,$line5    

for x in $line1Arg $line2Arg $lineArg $line4Arg $line5Arg; do

#might need to be -f0, I forget syntax
i=`echo $linex | cut -d"," -f1`

#this is from some code I found online, not sure if it's right.
linex=${linex#*,}

result=`grep $i $file`
oldarg=`grep $i $file |cut -d"=" -f2`

if [ -z $result ]
then
cp $file $tmpfile
echo $i=$x >> $tmpfile;
echo "$i added with value $x"
else
cat $file | sed "s/$i=$oldarg/$i=$x/g"> $tmpfile
echo "$i edited to $x"

fi

done
done
```

---

OLD STUFF

First grep to see if a file (or string or whatever) contains your value

```
 result=`grep $i $file`
 if [ -z $result ] 
 then
 cp $file $newfile
 echo "$i" >> $newfile
 else
 cat $file | sed "s/$i/$newi/g" > $newfile
 fi
```

in this case the sed command contains "s" for substitution, your old string, your new string, and "g" to do it globally (as opposed to once per file/line/etc). I also modified the way it added your value if it was not contained in the file. -z checks if a string is of zero length (which it will be if the grep returned nothing) and >> appends to the end of a file.

EDIT:

Also, going off the comments, I feel like I should explain "|" , ">" and ">>"

"|" pipe, pipes output to another function. That is, it uses the output to stdOut of the command to the left of the pipe as the input for stdIn of the command on the right of the pipe. Many shell commands use stdIn if an input file is not specified. This works really well with chaining commands together.

">" redirect, redirects output to a file instead of stdOut. This is useful if (like in your case) you want to move output to a file, not just have it sit in the console. This will write to the file from the beginning though, effectively overwriting whichever file output is redirected to.

">>" append, appends information to the end of a file instead of displaying it in stdOut. This means that the file can persist, but also have added to it the output of your program. this is useful if you need to add something more to the end of your file.

It may be hard to see where there are useful, but I hope it at least sheds some light on how they work and why I chose to use them in my answer to your question.

EDIT2:
added "then" to the code which I think is how to signal an structured "if" statement (such as if-else) instead of just a simple if (just if, no else). My shell programming is a little rusty, I hope this helps.

Edit3:
changed end-if to fi (because that's the correct syntax in shell. Also change $i to Echo $i because redirect directs the output of a command.

If you need to put a loop into this where $i is each variable to be matched in $linexarg it would look something like this

```
for i in $linexarg
do
#above code
done
```

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) is the reference I'm using to determine that.

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Ok. I think maybe im not being specific enough. Your code returns 'missing text missing'...from $file presumebaly. What i want is to append the end of the file if it is missing. I alsonwanr to add "$line1=$line1Arg" to $file if it is missing?

Comment: My code assumes that a file path is set in $file . Is this the case when you execute it?

Comment: Yes it is matt. I had to change it slightly to get it to work. I had to change $i >> $tmpfile to echo $i >> $tmpfile. But it doesnt add all missing entries. Secondly how do i loop over $linexArg to add them. In format $line1=$line1Arg ?

Comment: Further sh -x details added

Comment: That seems to work @Matt. Thanks a lot. Is there anyway to not edit if the $lineXArg is already set to what is specified in the script? I also had to remove one done command as i was getting an 'unexpected done' error

Comment: Yeah that makes sense because I removed a for loop. you could probably add a conditional for if oldarg = linex I'm not sure if that keeps everything logically sound. Glad we got this worked out :)

Comment: Just come back to this and it doesnt work. It does nit change values that already exists and only adds on missing entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/text string/value/' file > file.new
```

[`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Introduction) is a "stream editor" -- you pass it files or even pipe text into it, and it can manipulate the text in a Turing number of ways. This program reads the file (line-by-line), uses the [`s///`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) command to search for the regular expression "text string", and replaces the first instance on each line with the text "value".